# Scrapy on the Cloud

Tags: python, cloud, scrapy

I am thinking if there is the posibility instead of using scrapy with a large amount of proxies to use scrapy from multiple servers... example cloud computing.

Anybody has given this a shot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, these guys have: http://scrapinghub.com/scrapy-cloud.html